# Titanium Active Tab Issue

Tags: iphone, mobile, titanium

**Built in Appcelerator**

I am not sure if this is a bug or just bad code however, I have 5 tabs. The 5th window hides the tabgroup.

I have a on click event on the 5th window to set the active tab to the 2nd (index 1)

What's happening is, it's switching to the correct tab, but if I press another button both stay highlighted. One has the block around it the other just the icon is blue.

Any Ideas?

Code Used:

```
tabGroup.setActiveTab(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
tabGroup.setActiveTab(tab1);//tab1 is the tab has index = 1
```